# Why is Scala slow to initialize an Array of tuples?

Tags: scala, performance

This is the slow code

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val ret = Array.fill[(Int, Int, Int)](8000000){(0, 0, 0)}
    println(ret.size)
  }
}
```

It runs for 2 minutes. And then outputs

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

And this is the fast code

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val ret = Array.fill[Int](24000000){0}
    println(ret.size)
  }
}
```

It runs for 0.5 seconds.

My compilation option:

```
scalac Hello.scala
```

Why is there a huge gap?

Comment: Primitive array only needs allocation one time, for the array itself. Object array needs 1+N allocations, for the array itself and all the object inside

Comment: @texasbruce, it's actually caused by the incorrect heap memory setting, the default for scala in my system is Xmx256M Xms32M, not enough for this amount of data. I changed to Xmx1G Xms1G, the first code only takes 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

`Array[Int]` is an array of primitives.

`Array[(Int, Int, Int)]` is an array of objects.

(You can experiment with `Array[java.lang.Integer]`, which is an array of objects too.)

---

Something's with your settings, normally

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val ret = Array.fill[(Int, Int, Int)](8000000){(0, 0, 0)}
    println(ret.size)
  }
}
```

doesn't take long https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4p4GpYbHSqm7K6U3hwLdYw

Comment: But the gap shouldn't so huge, and notice that the first code initialize 8 million objects, the second one initialize 24 million integers

Comment: @TCX Something's with your settings, normally it doesn't take long https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4p4GpYbHSqm7K6U3hwLdYw

Comment: Looks like the default JVM heap memory is too small for this operation. The default option for `scala Hello` is Xmx256M Xms32M

Comment: When I manually increase it to Xmx1024M  Xms1024M, it's runs fast